# Vaadin 8 grid: How to display an image as tooltip in a grid cell?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I have an image in a grid cell and I want to show the enlarged image as tooltip. It should be possible with "setDescriptionGenerator". I tried the following:

```java
grid.addComponentColumn(probe -> {
            Image image = new Image("", new ThemeResource("img/" + probe.getImage()));
            image.setWidth(35, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
            image.setHeight(35, Unit.PERCENTAGE);

            return image;
        }).setCaption("Structure").setDescriptionGenerator(probe -> {
            Image image = new Image("", new ThemeResource("img/" + probe.getImage()));

            return image;
        });
```

But I get the error that I cannot return an image. It seems that with "setDescriptionGenerator" I can only set a String. Is it possible to write a custom description generator? Please give me an example.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can return only String type here I will offer you this workaround:

```java
 grid.addComponentColumn(probe -> {
        Image image = new Image("", new ThemeResource("img/" + probe.getImage()));
        image.setWidth(35, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        image.setHeight(35, Unit.PERCENTAGE);

        return image;
    }).setCaption("Structure").setDescriptionGenerator(probe -> {
            String imgSource = "img/" + probe.getImage();
            String html = "<img src=\" " + imgSource + "\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\">";
            return html;
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a really good idea. Do you know where I have to put the images? For the ThemeResource I place the images in src\main\webapp\VAADIN\themes\mytheme\img. But with html the images are not found there. I also tried the Vaadin basepath with the images in src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\images. This still does not work.

Comment: Please try `../VAADIN/themes/mytheme/img` or without those `..`. Also make sure that your image name contains extension

Comment: I tried many paths (even absolute ones with file://), but I always get the html displayed as text. The html seems not to be recognized in a grid description. I found this link: https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/8853 Did you get it to work in your Vaadin 8 grid?

Comment: Sorry for not responsing for quite long time. Hope [this](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/9121) will help you

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me! The link points to the CSS for the normal tooltips and in the mytheme is already set like this. However, this does not seem to work for the grid cell tooltip. I looked for something like v-grid-cell-tooltip.But I could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46812639), you should set a descriptionGenerator passing also the `ContentMode.HTML`

```
grid.addComponentColumn(probe -> {
    Image image = new Image("", new ThemeResource("img/" + probe.getImage()));
    image.setWidth(35, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    image.setHeight(35, Unit.PERCENTAGE);

    return image;
}).setCaption("Structure").setDescriptionGenerator(probe -> {
    String imgSource = "img/" + probe.getImage();
    String html = "<img src=\" " + imgSource + "\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\">";
    return html;
}, ContentMode.HTML);
```